# How do I use Unicode characters in Pod and perldoc?

Tags: perl, unicode, documentation, internationalization, perldoc

I need to use utf-8 characters in my perl-documentation.
If I use:

```
perldoc MyMod.pm
```

I see strange characters. If I use:

```
pod2text MyMod.pm
```

everything is fine.

I use Ubuntu/Debian.

```
$ locale
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Is there a HowTo about using special characters in Pod?

Here is a small example using german umlauts "Just a Test: äöüßÄÖ":

```
$ perldoc perl/MyMod.pm
<standard input>:72: warning: can't find character with input code 159
<standard input>:72: warning: can't find character with input code 150
MyMod(3)              User Contributed Perl Documentation             MyMod(3)

NAME
        MyMod.pm - Just a Test: Ã¤Ã¶Ã¼ÃÃÃ

perl v5.10.0                      2008-10-16                          MyMod(3)
```

Comment: What kind of strange characters? Question marks? Boxes? Weird ANSI formatting codes?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `=encoding utf-8` as the first POD directive in your file, and use a fairly recent `perldoc` (for example from 5.10-maint). Then it should work.

Comment: this answer seems to be correct. thank you. i found more details in "perldoc perlpod".

Comment: The doc indicates "=encoding utf8" rather than "=encoding utf-8". But with 5.18 on Ubuntu it seems unnecessary, and in 5.16 on Mac OS X 10.10.4 neither seems to work.

Answer (score 6):

Found this RT ticket.... http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=39000

This "bug" seems to be introduced with Perl 5.10 and perhaps this pod2man --utf8 needs to be used.

Answer (score 0):

perldoc -t MyMod.pm

From the perldoc manual:

-t Display pod using pod2text instead of Pod::Man and groff (-t is the default on win32 unless -n is specified)