# How can I use Unicode characters in Perl POD-derived man pages?

Tags: perl, unicode, internationalization, manpage, perl-pod

And if this isn't possible, what is the best practice for dealing with man pages derived from UTF-8-encoded POD?

The first thing to do in order to work with Unicode in POD is to use the directive

```
=encoding UTF-8
```

(as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207871/how-do-i-use-unicode-characters-in-pod-and-perldoc)). The `pod2text` and `pod2html` tools will work fine and produce perfect UTF-8-encoded output.

The `pod2man` tool, however, does not:

```
pod2man -u MyModule.pm | nroff -Tutf8 -man | less
```

Neither does `perldoc`. Non-ASCII characters are all mangled or X-ed out. There is [some inconclusive discussion](https://rt.perl.org/rt3//Public/Bug/Display.html?id=111448) on perlbug on whether this might be a bug in `pod2man` or **roff*.

Since my module deals with Unicode specifically and is intended for distribution on CPAN, Unicode-enabled man pages are a must.

I am using Perl 5.14.2, perldoc 3.15, and *roff 1.21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of `perldoc`, `pod2man`, `nroff` can be made to handle Unicode UTF-8 characters correctly. Unfortunately the Perl installers such as Build.PL and the *cpan* program can't yet. So unless you do some fiddling by hand during the installation the installed man pages will be broken.

These all work correctly for my [minimal example](https://gist.github.com/3964396):

```
perldoc lib/MyModule.pm        # works as of 3.16 (@Schwern)
perldoc -t lib/MyModule.pm     # display with pod2text
pod2man -u lib/MyModule.pm     # produces UTF-8 man page
pod2man -u lib/MyModule.pm | nroff -Tutf8 -man - -Kutf8 | less
```

`nroff` only works when you pass the *input* encoding (`-K`) through to *groff* as well ([source](http://www.simplicidade.org/notes/archives/2012/07/tip_homebrew_perldoc_groff.html)); you have to protect it with the end-of-options `-` switch.

This is nice. However, most users will want to install the documentation and later consult it with `man MyModule` or `perldoc MyModule`. In the case of `perldoc`, your options are to either use a very recent version (3.16) or the `-t` switch.

In the case of `man`, if you use Build.PL (Module::Build) to install a module you can repair the broken generated docs just before the installation:

```
perl Build.PL
./Build
# now overwrite the broken man pages:
pod2man -u -s 3pm lib/MyModule.pm blib/libdoc/MyModule.3pm
./Build install
```

Lovely! Now you can view the man page with `man MyModule`.

If you use *cpan* to install the module your man pages will be broken. (You can try the same workaround on your local CPAN build directory, eg. `~/.cpan/build`, which should also work.)

Answer (score 3):

You're in luck!  [This bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=26121) appears to have been [fixed in Pod::Perldoc 3.16](https://metacpan.org/source/MALLEN/Pod-Perldoc-3.17/Changes#L46).  So just update Pod::Perldoc and half the problem is solved.

However, pod2man comes from a [different distribution](https://metacpan.org/release/podlators) and is a wholly different code base.  It is still broken for UTF-8.  Unfortunately it's what the Perl installers use to generate man pages.

Comment: I don't have a perldoc 3.16 available but I will take your word for it, thanks. Also, `pod2man` does have a `--utf8` switch which works just fine.

Comment: I'm still having an issue with Perlpod 3.19 of Perl 5.18.2; shouldn't it be fixed?

Comment: @U.Windl Looks like [later versions have additional Unicode fixes](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Pod-Perldoc). As always, try upgrading. 5.18.2 is six years old. You may also want to try upgrading [podlators](https://metacpan.org/release/podlators) which contains pod2man.