# Why does perldoc evaluate 'Münster' as 'Muenster'

Tags: perl, utf-8, perldoc, perl-pod

I have a simple POD text file:

```
$ cat test.pod 
=encoding UTF-8

Münster
```

It is encoded in UTF-8, as per this literal hex dump of the file:

```
00000000  3d 65 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e  67 20 55 54 46 2d 38 0a  |=encoding UTF-8.|
00000010  0a 4d c3 bc 6e 73 74 65  72 0a                    |.M..nster.|
0000001a
```

The "ü" is being encoded as the two bytes C3 and BC.

But when I run `perldoc` on the file it is turning my lovely formatted UTF-8 characters into ASCII.

What's more, it is correctly handling the German language convention of representing "ü" as "ue".

```
$ perldoc test.pod | cat
TEST(1)               User Contributed Perl Documentation              TEST(1)

Muenster

perl v5.16.3                      2014-06-10                           TEST(1)
```

Why is it doing this?

Is there an additional declaration I can put into my file to stop it from happening?

---

After additional investigation with `App::perlbrew` I've found the difference comes from having a particular version of Pod::Perldoc.

```
perl-5.10.1    3.14_04    Muenster
perl-5.12.5    3.15_02    Muenster
perl-5.14.4    3.15_04    Muenster
perl-5.16.2    3.17       Münster
perl-5.16.3    3.19       Muenster
perl-5.16.3    3.17       Münster
perl-5.17.3    3.17       Münster
perl-5.18.0    3.19       Muenster
perl-5.18.1    3.23       Münster
```

However I would still like, if possible, a way to make Pod::Perldoc 3.14, 3.15, and 3.19 behave "correctly".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found this RT ticket http://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=39000

This "bug" seems to be introduced with Perl 5.10 and perhaps this was solved in later versions.

Also see: [How can I use Unicode characters in Perl POD-derived man pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065495/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-in-perl-pod-derived-man-pages) and [incorrect behaviour of perldoc with UTF-8 texts](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=492037).

You should add the latest available version of [**Pod::Perldoc**](https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Perldoc) as a dependency.

Comment: Interesting that according to https://metacpan.org/source/MALLEN/Pod-Perldoc-3.23/Changes RT #39000 was fixed in 3.15_12 but I see a regression in 3.19.

Comment: The solution I settled on was to add `Pod::Perldoc 3.21` as a dependency, which should ensure that anybody using the module has a recent enough version of `perldoc` to actually read the POD!

Comment: Yes, something strange is cooking there. Using the latest version is what I can suggest.

Comment: If you edit your answer to include "add the latest version of Pod::Perldoc as a dependency" I'll mark it as **Accepted** :-)

Comment: **Update:** Pod::Perldoc 3.24, released August 19th 2014, now supports full UTF-8 text! Read more [from Mark Allen on blogs.perl.org](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_allen/2014/09/if-your-core-perl-documentation-uses-encoding-please-test-the-new-perldoc-release.html).