# What string should be used to specify encoding in Perl POD, "utf8", "UTF-8" or "utf-8"?

Tags: perl, encoding, utf-8, documentation

It is possible to write Perl documentation in UTF-8. To do it you should write in your POD:

```
=encoding NNN
```

But what should you write instead `NNN`? Different sources gives different answers.

- [perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) says that that should be `=encoding utf8`
- [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13065495/how-can-i-use-unicode-characters-in-perl-pod-derived-man-pages) states that it should be `=encoding UTF-8`
- and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207871/how-do-i-use-unicode-characters-in-pod-and-perldoc) tells me to write `=encoding utf-8`

What is the correct answer? What is the correct string to be written in POD?

Comment: Technically, none of those.  Unicode and UTF-8 are different encodings.

Comment: To be even more pedantic, unicode is a decoding, not an encoding.

Comment: Thank you =) You are right. I'll remove the term Unicode from the question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
=encoding UTF-8
```

[According to IANA, charset names are case-insensitive](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets), so `utf-8` is the same.

[`utf8` is Perl's lax variant of UTF-8.](http://p3rl.org/Encode#UTF-8-vs.-utf8-vs.-UTF8) However, for safety, you want to be strict to your POD processors.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I wanted to get =) One more thing. So [perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) with its `=encoding utf8` is incoreect. Do you think is is worth proposing a patch?

Comment: It's not a big thing. Do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

As daxim points out, I have been misled. `=encoding=UTF-8` and `=encoding=utf-8` apply the strict encoding, and `=encoding=utf8` is the lenient encoding:

```
$ cat enc-test.pod
=encoding ENCNAME

=head1 TEST '\344\273\245\376\202\200\200\200\200\200'

=cut
```

(here `\xxx` means the literal byte with value `xxx`. `\344\273\245` is a valid UTF-8 sequence, `\376\202\200\200\200\200\200` is not)

### `=encoding=utf-8`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/ENCNAME/utf-8/' enc-test.pod | pod2cpanhtml | grep /h1
>TEST &#39;&#20197;&#27492;&#65533;&#39;</a></h1>
```

### `=encoding=utf8`:

```
$ perl -pe 's/ENCNAME/utf8/' enc-test.pod | pod2cpanhtml | grep /h1
Code point 0x80000000 is not Unicode, no properties match it; ...
Code point 0x80000000 is not Unicode, no properties match it; ...
Code point 0x80000000 is not Unicode, no properties match it; ...
>TEST &#39;&#20197;&#2147483648;&#39;</a></h1>
```

---

They are all equivalent. The argument to `=encoding` is expected to be a name recognized by the [`Encode::Supported`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode%3a%3aSupported) module. When you drill down into that document, you see

- the canonical encoding name is `utf8`
- the name `UTF-8` is an alias for `utf8`, and
- names are case insensitive, so `utf-8` is equivalent to `UTF-8`

What's the best practice? I'm not sure. I don't think you go wrong using the official IANA name (as per daxim's answer), but you can't go wrong following the official Perl documentation, either.

Comment: That alias part of the documentation mislead you, hyphen and no hyphen are treated differently. Try: `perl -MEncode=decode -MDevel::Peek=Dump -e'Dump decode "utf-8", "\xfe\x82\x80\x80\x80\x80\x80", Encode::FB_CROAK | Encode::LEAVE_SRC'`

Comment: Wow! Thank you for doing such great work for showing the difference between utf8 and utf-8.